# Get the top most related a element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a id="1">Item 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="2">Item 1.1<a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a id="3">Item 1.1.1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a id="4">Item 1.1.1.1</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to get the `id` of top most `ul > li > a` tag (that is `#1`) from the `a` with `id="4"`. I'm trying like the below to get it:

```
 var getId = $(this).parents('ul:last > a:first').attr("id");
```

I'm getting `undefined`.

Here depth may vary. I don't want to use `parent().parent().parent()` multiple times, because this tree may have much deeper child's, say up to `1.1.1.1.1.1` (5 levels) for that if I want to get the `id` of top most parent I need to use 5 times `parent()`, I don't want that. Is any other solution is available?

Comment: Is it always the same depth?

Comment: i dont want to use parent().parent().parent() multile parent kewords, becaude this tree may have much deeper childs, say up tp 1.1.1.1.1.1(5 level) for that if i want to get the id of top most parent i need to use 5 times parent(), i dont want that, any other solution is available?

Comment: @Darren depth may vary..

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have reopened this as that question is not a duplicate. In this case the element the OP is looking to find is not a direct parent, and also the accepted answer in that question is terrible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sure thanks.

Comment: `var getId = $('#4').parents('ul li').last().children('a').attr("id");`

Comment: What's `this` in this context?

Comment: You can try using `parents()`. Also I assume that first `ul` will be nested inside a `div`, so you can try something like $(this).parents('div').find('ul').Not sure though.

Comment: I have edited my answer can you please try again, as Its worked for me now.

Answer (score 0):

As I have already commented, you can use `.parents()`.

**Note** *I have assumed that these structure are enclosed in a `div`.*

Also I have updated `id`s to simulate multiple structure and have added a event listener to `a` tag. You should avoid it in your code and should be either on a class or a specific selector.

#### Code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/4xau5s3d/)

```js
$('a').on("click", function() {
  var ul = $(this).parents('div').find('ul:first');
  var a = $(ul).find('a:first')[0]
  console.log(a.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="first_1">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a id="first_2">Item 1.1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="second_1">Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a id="second_2">Item 2.1</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a id="second_3">Item 2.1.1</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a id="second_4">Item 2.1.1.1</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="third_1">Item 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a id="third_2">Item 3.1</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a id="third_3">Item 3.1.1</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a id="third_4">Item 3.1.1.1.1</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a id="third_4">Item 3.1.1.1</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### Edit 1

Logic:

- Search for div parent.
- Inside this parent, we will get all structure. Loop over these `ul`s and search for current id.
- Based of the result, get the selected `ul` and find the first `a` tag.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/4xau5s3d/1/).

#### Code

```js
$('a').on("click", function() {
  var div = $(this).parents('div');
  var uls = div.children();

  var selectedUl = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < uls.length; i++) {
    var _list = $(uls[i]).find('#' + $(this).attr("id"));
    if (_list.length > 0) {
      selectedUl = uls[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  var a = $(selectedUl).find('a:first')[0];
  console.log(a.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="first_1">Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a id="first_2">Item 1.1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="second_1">Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a id="second_2">Item 2.1</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a id="second_3">Item 2.1.1</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a id="second_4">Item 2.1.1.1</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="third_1">Item 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a id="third_2">Item 3.1</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a id="third_3">Item 3.1.1</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a id="third_4">Item 3.1.1.1.1</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a id="third_4">Item 3.1.1.1</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: actualy all the three items are in one div. not in a individual separate div.

Comment: so does they have similar `id`s? I mean `<a>` tags?

Comment: @VijayKumar I meant similar like in my case, they are `first_` and then ID... If not, is text similar? like 1.1, 1.1.1. etc etc?

Comment: Id's are having unique numbers not with prefixed text, say id's are like 1,2,6,5,4, and so on

Comment: @VijayKumar I have updated my answer. Hope it helps. Though I would suggest you to encapsulate every structure inside its own `div`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```js
//Store all ul
$elems = $('#4').parents('ul');

// Get id of first ul > a
console.log($($elems[$elems.size() - 1]).find('a').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
 <li>
    <a id="1">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a id="2">Item 1.1<a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a id="3">Item 1.1.1</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
              <a id="4">Item 1.1.1.1</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('a').on("click", function () {
         alert($(this).closest('div').find('a:first').attr('id'));
     });
});


<div id="div_container">
<ul>
<li>
    <a id="1">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a id="2">Item 1.1<a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a id="3">Item 1.1.1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a id="4">Item 1.1.1.1</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can get using last with parents method , try following code :-

```
var getId = $('#4').parents('ul a').last().attr("id");
```

It may help you

Comment: Nice job copying my answer. However it's wrong for the same reason mine was - the `a` is not a parent of the `#4` element.

Comment: Seriously? Now will you copy the answer in the comment too?

Comment: what you wan to say?

Comment: Sorry Guys I have edited my answer and its perfectly worked for me .